# Azure AD B2C Password reset does not work when the users are created using the graph API and Sign In Name as Username

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure AD B2C with Username login for my application. I am creating,updating and deleting users using the graph API and there is no way of adding a primary email programatically (I can only add the "OtherMail" property in the graph api) so as to later use it in the password reset policy for verification. So now I have no way of resetting the password using my password reset policy.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can read/write the user's Email address using `strongAuthenticationEmailAddress` attribute within the B2C policy. This attribute can only be read or written to by the B2C policy execution.

Typically, at user sign-in, you will read `strongAuthenticationEmailAddress` and then check if it is empty. If it is, then ask the user to input/verify Email address before proceeding further to the next orchestration step.

Take a look at this sample to get started:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin

Comment: The question is will I be able to write to the strongAuthenticationEmailAddress using graph API programatically?

Comment: Also, as you are saying at User Sign-in I should read the strongAuthenticationEmailAddress but the claims don't have that field visible or exposed, I tried changing the settings for the b2c portal but there is no option to make it available.

Comment: You cannot use Microsoft Graph Api to write to the strongAuthenticationEmailAddress attribute. However, you can read/write it from within the custom policy or through the portal. The policy file that I linked above, shows how to read and write the strongAuthenticationEmailAddress attrubue. Also, through portal, you can change it by selecting the user and then changing the Email value listed inside Authentication contact info setting.

Comment: My users are getting created by admins who inturn are local account users, So these admins can create new users using the Application UI (not the b2c signup policy ui) but as I am using username signup, the admins enter the username, password some custom claims thats it. Now when the user just created logs in, everything works fine but password reset doesnt work as it doesnt have strongAuthenticationEmailAddress to verify.

Comment: Now what I understand from your explaination above is that I will have to check when the newly created user logs in if he has strongAuthenticationEmailAddress set, (which he will always have as null as the user is created by graph api) now it it is not set I should take the user to a different custom policy which will have him enter the email address. Am I right in this approach and is this feasible?

Comment: I am currently using the inbuild SignIn policy and Password Reset policy

Comment: Within the custom policy, you can simply check the value of strongAuthenticationEmailAddress and if it is empty force the user to verify their email and then set the value. This sample policy is a good start: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin.